# AppEngine log not accepting context

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-platform

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/logs/) I can use `log.Errorf(ctx, "whatever: %v", err)`

Somehow that isn't working for me. I have `ctx` declared as an `appengine.Context`, as in the documentation example, but Go is complaining that I need to pass a `net/context` instead!? I would assume that AppEngine would **ONLY** accept an AppEngine context, and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

AppEngine log expects `context.Context` created by `appengine.NewContext()` or it's derivatives.

Comment: That's what I thought, but when I give it that, it's telling me that it wants `net/context` instead. I have tried importing both `appengine/log` and `google.golang.org/appengine/log`